# segmentation-fault .. AnsiStringToUnicodeString as first debug-error-line .. doobious class-hieracy

Tags: c++, oop, virtual

I tried to make the classes hold RAII standards (as I get it .. I'm a hobby programmer), but the compiler/debugger complained about missing constructors (with empty brackets), so I added them + set_value() functions.

The point of elaborating so much on a simple rectangle is to lift the cloudiness of integrating GUI-types (top-down types like buttons and text-fields) from the foreground problem I'm trying to handle: openGL 2D & 3d graphics living in a lower-left coordinatesystem.

```
enum class eAnker:int{
    high_left,
    high_right,
    low_left,
    low_right,
}

class anker
{
    friend node_handler;
    public:
        anker(){};
        anker(glm::dvec2 Vec2):pPoint( new glm::dvec2(Vec2) ){};
        anker(glm::dvec2 Vec2, eAnker ea):pPoint( new glm::dvec2(Vec2) ),anker_type(ea){};
        virtual ~anker(){ delete pPoint; };
        void set_value(glm::dvec2){pPoint=new glm::dvec2(v);}
        void set_anchor_type( eAnker ea){ anker_type=ea; }
        bool operator<( anker& a ){ return (pPoint->x<a.pPoint->x)<(pPoint->y<a.pPoint->y); };
    protected:
        glm::dvec2* pPoint;
        eAnker anker_type;
};


class nRect:public anker
{
    friend node_handler;
    public:
        nRect(){};
        nRect(glm::dvec2 p):anker(p){};
        nRect(glm::dvec2 p,double lineHeight, double letterWidth):anker(p),plHeight( new double(lineHeight)),       plWidth( new double(letterWidth) ){};
        virtual ~nRect(){
            delete plHeight;
            delete plWidth;
        };
        void set_dims( double Ww, double Lh ){
            plWidth= new double(Ww*LETTER_PIXEL_WIDTH);
            plHeight=new double(Lh*LINE_PIXEL_HEIGHT);
        }
    protected:
        double* plHeight;
        double* plWidth;
};


class node:public nRect
{
    friend node_handler;
    public:
    node(){};
    node(glm::dvec2 p):nRect(p){};
    node(glm::dvec2 p, double wW, double lH):nRect(p,wW,lH){};
    virtual ~node(){};
    void mouse_up(){
        on_click();
    };
    virtual void on_click(){
        /*
        bool b = !set_bit::is_closed(myBits);
        set_bit::as_closed(myBits,b);
        */
    };
protected:
    vector<node>::iterator iParent;
    bitset<32> myBits;
    string string_data;
    double my_ratio; 
    glm::dvec2 cursor_old;
};

class node_handler
{
    public:
        node_handler(){}
        ~node_handler(){};
        void set_root( glm::dvec2 anker, double pixel_width, double pixel_height ){
            if(!root_lock){
                node n(anker,pixel_width/25.0d,pixel_height/12.0d)  ;
                n.string_data="root";
                n.iParent = nodes.end();
                nodes.resize(10);
                nodes.at(0) = n ;
                current=nodes.begin();
                root_lock=true;
                node_counter++;
            }
            else{
                //cout << "BEEP nodes.root-error\n" << char(7);
            }
        }
        void split_current( double ratio, bool as_horizontal ){
            pair<node,node> res = split(current,ratio,as_horizontal);
            res.first.string_data="-closer";
            res.first.iParent=current;
            res.second.string_data="-farther";
            res.second.iParent=current;
            if(node_counter<int(nodes.size()) ) {
                nodes.at(node_counter)=res.first;
                current=nodes.begin()+node_counter;
                node_counter++;
                nodes.at(node_counter)=res.second;
                node_counter++;
            }
            else{
                cout << "no handler-space for more nodes\n" ;
            }
        //no errors so far. when leaving split_current(..), the execution halts with a SIGSEGV
}
    protected:
        int node_counter=0;
    private:
        pair<node,node>split( vector<node>::iterator& this_node, double ratio, bool as_horizontal ){
            this_node->my_ratio=ratio;
            double firstW, firstH;
            double secW, secH;
            glm::dvec2 afirst, asecond;
            if(as_horizontal ){
                // set values
            }
            return make_pair<node,node>( node(afirst ,firstW, firstH), node(asecond ,secW, secH) ) ;
        }
        vector<node>::iterator current;
        vector<node> nodes;
        bool root_lock{false};
};
/////////////////////
```

### test in main:

```
node_handler nh;
    glm::dvec2 minor=glm::dvec2(0.0d, 0.0d);
    double width=800.0d;
    double height=600.0d;
nh.set_root(minor,width,height);
nh.split_current( 1.0d/10.0d , true );
//see nh.split_current() where SIGSEGV happens
```

---

```
The debug error-trace leaves 10 lines, noone pointing to a specific line in my code:

ntdll!RtlAnsiSringToUnicodeString()
??()
std::basic_Ostream<.....
std::clog()
std::clog()
??()
msvcat!_iob()
vtable for ct::anker
std::piecewise_construct
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve],  ie a small self-contained piece of code that we can copy and compile that reproduces the problem you are having.

Comment: Richard .. I've made a full rewrite of the question. There is a lot of code, but you'll recognize most of it to be boiler-plating.

Comment: What probably doesn't help: your primitive members are left unitialised by certain constructor overloads, so if (as they probably will) they get read subsequently, you get undefined behaviour, and anything can go wrong. Ensure your primitive members are always initialised to determinate values. Use in-class member initialisers to set constant defaults (to avoid repetition).

Comment: underscore, I've made sure that all nodes so far are initialized through the constructors. If we call the constructors with empty parameters for default constructors then: they are there because the compiler complained about their absense. I don't use them. You can follow the three nodes that is part of the setup: the root and the two splitted nodes that it provides parametrs for. Giving values to  afirst ,firstW, firstH is 'a secret of the trade' ... just parting root-rectangle into two rects that fills it out. They will become children of a control-button-resizer.

Comment: ok, got it .. the nodes created are local to to the split(..) function
return make_pair<node,node>( node(afirst ,firstW, firstH), node(asecond ,secW, secH) ) ;
can be changed to return make_pair(node*, node*).
... why am I surprised every time?

Answer (score 0):

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788946/what-can-you-return-from-a-function-and-expect-it-to-be-alive-at-arrival?noredirect=1#comment105720561_59788946) is a follow-up, on the same code, that probably contain the proper answer to the erratic behavior described. In short (as I understand it): classes with pointer-members needs customized copy/assignment operators these they are at work, without your notice, behind the code you write .. the default ones won't work. 
I didn't provide them.