# what /can/ you return from a function .. and expect it to be alive at arrival?

Tags: c++, return

Once again I got cought on expecting a function to return a proper value and then be disapointed .. getting odd behavior and misleading debug-information instead.
It's fairly well known, that you cannot return a local variable from a function and expect it to arrive as you would expect. Testing

```
int i=2;
int k=4;
return make_pair<int,int>(i*i,k*k);
```

Does indeed return something respectable. But using more elaborate objects than simple types seems to catch me *every time*.
So, is there any formality that I can use for discriminating on what can and what cannot be returned safely from a function?
                        ----------- added on edit: ------------
    Here is the example that does not work, taken brutally out of context.
    Problem-context is a (to be GUI) tree of rectangles for the screen.
    Class node inherits from a base (rectangle) containing 3 pointers to plain types (again, used to make values stick) .. the base uses new in constructor

```
pair<node,node> node_handler::split( vector<node>::iterator& this_node, double ratio, bool as_horizontal ){
//this_node becomes parents to the split-twins
    this_node->my_ratio=ratio;
    double firstW, firstH;
    double secW, secH;
    glm::dvec2 afirst, asecond;
    if(as_horizontal ){
        firstW = *this_node->plWidth*LETTER_PIXEL_WIDTH;
        firstH = *this_node->plHeight*LINE_PIXEL_HEIGHT*ratio;
        afirst = *this_node->pPoint;
        secW   = firstW;
        secH   = LINE_PIXEL_HEIGHT*(*this_node->plHeight)*(1.0d-ratio);
        asecond= afirst+glm::dvec2(0.0d, firstH);
    }
    else{
        firstW = ratio*(*this_node->plWidth)*LETTER_PIXEL_WIDTH;
        firstH = *this_node->plHeight*LINE_PIXEL_HEIGHT;
        afirst = *this_node->pPoint;
        secW   = (1.0d*ratio)*(*this_node->plWidth)*LETTER_PIXEL_WIDTH;
        secH   = firstH;
        asecond= afirst+glm::dvec2(firstW,0.0d);
    }
    return make_pair<node,node>( node(afirst ,firstW, firstH) , node(asecond ,secW, secH)  ) ;
}
```

Comment: This is a very vague question, but generally anything you return *by value* is fine. If you return a pointer or reference, the lifetime of that object must outlive the local function.

Comment: So you show code that you say **works** and you say that some other code that you haven't shown doesn't work? Show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: "you cannot return a local variable from a function and expect it to arrive as you would expect" -- this is simply wrong.

Comment: Pete Becker, I'm sort of not surprised that it won't work, but not why (until now). I followed constructors and destructors and noted that the pair<> was destructed as soon as constructed .. and execution would halt after this.

Comment: should I assume that the default copy-constructor for node is insufficient, if the above example causes execution to halt without pointing to a specific code-line that fails?

Comment: a fuller code-set should be present at
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761144/segmentation-fault-ansistringtounicodestring-as-first-debug-error-line-doo)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can return anything from a function.

Now when you return a pointer or a reference to something that is only local, then you have a problem.

Solutions:

1. Return copies (OK with copy elision anyway)
2. Return `shared_ptr<>`/`unique-ptr<>` for something that must not be copied.
3. Return only basic types and pass to the function a reference to an object that might be modified.

Do not create something in the function that needs to be manually destroyed layer (say, a pointer created with `new`).

Comment: Note: The more modern the C++ version, the more I'd discourage #3, virtual "returns" via the passing of mutable references, especially if the argument is also used as an input. From the caller side, the code looks identical to "safe" code that passes by value or const reference, but if it's not 100% obvious that the argument is a logical return (e.g. stuff like `std::swap`), people may get thrown by the in-place mutation, assuming it was purely an input value. Beyond that, it means you must explicitly declare variables ahead of time, and can't benefit from using `auto` to infer return types.

Comment: I wonder where I've made errors in the passed .. I've felt forced to use pointers if I want to make values stick (hench the rectangle-pointers). Most work will end in vector<> or list<> .. without me realizing that /that's/ the only allocator needed. My antidote on the example at hand is, again, making a pair<node*,node*> instead. It solves the problem at hand, but may not be the best solution. I'm very greatful for all your input and suggestions.

Comment: @ShadowRanger in Windows API, the vast majority of functions work that way so the user has to cope.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: The Windows API is largely C compatible, so references aren't even a thing in the core API. What little true C++-like features it uses in the peripheral parts of the API usually pre-date reliable/guaranteed copy-elision, and often use the return value for a status code rather than raising exceptions (again, C heritage, and requiring all programs to use exceptions was considered bad form), so #3 is the only option. Sure, the user has to cope with existing APIs, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to write *new* APIs that are unnecessarily slow/confusing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the Windows API is largely a C++ api. The remnants of C are only to older APIS. Most newer api , COM, Ribbon, Sensors, DirectX, Direct2D, Media Foundation, UWP . [....] is C++ and still, it uses the #3 form.  Besides, C++ does not always mean copy elision and you cannot expect the API to be compatible only with C++ 17.

Answer (score 0):

It's dawning on me, that classes containing pointer-members reasonably has to have custom copy/assignment operators. I never got to grips with the "rho" variable referred to in the books I read at the time ... "right_hand_object" it must be! That's my epiphany. It was following the business of the constructors and your talk of copyable objects that squeezed this old rho-problem of mine.

I'm sorry for having spread my frustration on you.